# Datagrid: Calculate Avg or Sum for column in Footer 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, report

I have a datagrid getting bound to a dataset, and I want to display the average result in the footer for a column populated with integers.

The way I figure, there's 2 ways I can think of:

1."Use the **Source**, Luke"
In the code where I'm calling DataGrid.DataBind(), use the DataTable.Compute() method (*or in my case DataSet.DataTable(0).Compute()*). For example:

```
Dim strAverage = DataTable.Compute("Avg(ColumnName)", "")
```

But once I have this, how can I insert it into the footer?

2."**Bound** for Glory"
Using the DataGrid.ItemDataBound event, and calculating a running total from every ListItemType.Item and ListItemType.AlternatingItem, finally displaying in ListItemType.Footer. For example:

```
Select Case e.Item.ItemType
    Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem
        runningTotal += CInt(e.Item.Cells(2).Text)
    Case ListItemType.Footer
        e.Item.Cells(2).Text = runningTotal/DataGrid.Items.Count
End Select
```

This just feels wrong, plus I would have to make sure the runningTotal is reset on every DataBind.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if either are necessarily better, but two *alternate* ways would be:

1. Manually run through the table once you hit the footer and calculate from the on-screen text
2. Manually retrieve the data and do the calculation separately from the bind

Of course, #2 sort of offsets the advantages of data binding (assuming that's what you're doing).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [DannySmurf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409/aspnet-datagrid-in-footer-calculate-avg-or-sum-for-column#9426), your first answer made me see sense. (*Why do we always look for that magic solution?*).

For reference, here's what I ended up doing: (*Warning: VB below, may not contain enough semicolons*)

```
Case ListItemType.Footer
    e.Item.Cells(0).Text = "Average"
    For i As Integer = 3 To 8
        Dim runningTotal As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataGridItem In DataGrid.Items
            If IsNumeric(row.Cells(i).Text) Then
                runningTotal += CInt(row.Cells(i).Text)
            End If
        Next
    e.Item.Cells(i).Text = Math.Round(runningTotal / DataGrid.Items.Count, 0)
    Next
End Select
```

I needed to do it for several columns (hence 3 to 8), ultimately why I was looking for the magical solution.